# Random/Irregular pulse animation on imageview in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I need to implement a random "pulse" animation on an imageview.
Random, because I don't want a simple loop animation which repeat it forever each x seconds. The pulsation has to be irregular.

I need a random delay, random duration, and if it's possible random value for fromValue and toValue.

My code for a simple pulse animation, repeat each 5 sec, with an opacity to 0 from 1 :

```
    var pulseAnimation:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    pulseAnimation.duration = 5.0
    pulseAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(float: 0.0)
    pulseAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(float: 1.0)
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    myimageview.layer.addAnimation(pulseAnimation, forKey: "opacity")
```

If I write something like :

```
    pulseAnimation.duration = arc4random(....) //I will have a "fixed" random value
```

How can I do to implement irregular values ?

Answer (score 2):

`arc4random()` and `arc4random_uniform()` are as random as you can get. No seeding is required and they are cryptographic quality.

For a range use `arc4random_uniform()` instead of using the modular operator on `arc4random()`.

What you don't want to use is `rand()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a method :

```
    for loopNumber in 1...5 {

        let myImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "nameImageView")
        myImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
        self.view.addSubview(myImageView)

        var pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")

        pulseAnimation.fromValue = Double(arc4random_uniform(6)+1)/10
        pulseAnimation.toValue = Double(arc4random_uniform(6)+2)/10
        pulseAnimation.duration = Double(loopNumber)            
        pulseAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity

        myImageView.layer.addAnimation(pulseAnimation, forKey: "opacity")
    }
```